# Does PHP have a method to convert an array with objects into an array with the objects' given method output?

Tags: php, arrays

I will try to explain what I want to accomplish with this method using an example:

You have an object`Person` with the method `getName()` which returns `PersonName`.

Converting `[PersonA, PersonB]` into `[PersonNameA, PersonNameB]`.

I know PHP has a method `array_column` to reach this with properties. But I am wondering if there is also a method to do this with objects' methods.

Comment: The method you are looking for is [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Comment: Are you asking to get methods' names only? You can iterate and use `get_class_methods`. But you can't actually call methods on an array.

Comment: If you always want to return the name from the class, you can use `__toString()` in your classes and have it return `getName()`. Then you get the name by casting the object to a string.

Comment: He wants to call the method getName() for each object in the array and build a new array with those names returned from the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the usage of [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) that [@axiax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac) mentioned in his comment, you might feed it a closure for a first argument like this:

```
<?php

class Person
{
    private $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$personA = new Person();
$personB = new Person();

$personA->setName('bob');
$personB->setName('alice');

$objects = [
    $personA,
    $personB
];

$names = array_map(
    function(Person $p) {
        return $p->getName();
    },
    $objects
);

var_dump($names); // ['bob', 'alice']
```

Comment: Have you tested this? `array_map` should not modify the existing array, but instead return a new array, so `$names = array_map( ..., $objects);`, after which you can var_dump `$names`.

Comment: In my haste, I was thinking of array_walk.